# Reset a renewcommand

Tags: macros, environments, templates

I have found a [Resumé template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/two-column-one-page-cv) in Latex. I would like to change the following part of the template but my knowledge of Latex is not that extended.

```
% Every \item can be followed by one or more paragraphs
% of description:
%
% |[
% \item{date range}{company}{role}
%
% Description of what achieved during this application.
% ]|
\newenvironment{eventlist}{%
    \newcommand*\inskip{}
    \renewcommand\item[3]{%
    \inskip%
    {\raggedleft\sc ##1\\[1pt]}
    {##2}\\[2pt]
    {\Large\it ##3}
    \medskip
    \renewcommand\inskip{\bigskip}}}
    {\bigskip}
```

I would like to add (optional) an enumerate in the description. Like this:

```
% |[
% \item{date range}{company}{role}
%
% Description of what achieved during this application.
%    \begin{enumerate}
%      \item Foo
%      \item Bar
%    \end{enumerate}
% More description of what achieved during this application.
% ]|
```

How would you do this? Is this even possible because the `\item` is redefined if I'm correct?

Comment: I don't not advise to use those `latextemplate` stuff. They contain a lot of errors, actually.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Did you mean 'I don't recommend using that `latextemplate` stuff. ...'? Or 'I recommend not using...'?

Comment: Based only on that snippet, I would recommend avoiding this template! It is using commands which were deprecated 20+ years ago, and needlessly redefining a key LaTeX command.

Comment: @cfr: Damned typo of mine... I meant "**I don't advise to use ..**" ... Thanks!

Comment: Just change `\renewcommand\item` into `\newcommand\event` in the definition of `eventlist` and use `\event` in those cases; then you'll be able to use `\item` in the `enumerate`.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real fix but rather a workaround where you avoid using `\item` in the environment:

Example

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{eventListTest}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\begin{document}

\begin{eventlist}
\item{Data range}
     {Company}
     {Role}

  Description of what achieved during this application.\\
   \begin{easylist}[enumerate]
      & Foo~:
      && Sub item.
      && Another sub item.
      & Bar~:
    \end{easylist}
\end{eventlist}
\end{document}
```

Class: eventListTest.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{eventListTest}

\LoadClass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage[hmargin=1.25cm,vmargin=1.25cm,twocolumn,columnsep=1.25cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{bookman,etoolbox,hyperref,marvosym,needspace,tabularx,xcolor}

\newenvironment{eventlist}{%
    \newcommand*\inskip{}
    \renewcommand\item[3]{%
    \inskip%
    {\raggedleft\sc ##1\\[1pt]}
    {##2}\\[2pt]
    {\Large\it ##3}
    \medskip
    \renewcommand\inskip{\bigskip}}}
    {\bigskip}
```

[More information about easylist](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/easylist/easylist-doc.pdf)

[image]

EDITED: Added an example.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you elaborate on your answer, i.e. providing a full example and a screen shot?

Comment: Can you update the code to use LaTeX2e font commands? `\it` and `\sc` are long deprecated, for example, and ought not be used.