# What is the purpose of this \newcommand*, \inskip?

Tags: spacing, macros

I'm editing a resume template (and I've read it's [not advised](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220473/reset-a-renewcommand#comment518054_220473), but as a newbie it's my best starting point), and I don't understand what the purpose of creating `\inskip` is:

```
% Every \item can be followed by one or more paragraphs
% of description:
%
% |[
% \item{date range}{company}{role}
%
% Description of what achieved during this application.
% ]|
\newenvironment{eventlist}{%
    \newcommand*\inskip{}
    \renewcommand\item[3]{%
    \inskip%
    {\textbf{##3}\hfill\textsc{##1}\\[1pt]}
    {##2}\\[2pt]
    \renewcommand\inskip{\bigskip}}}
    {\bigskip}
```

It does not appear anywhere else in the class file, nor the .tex file. It appears to me that it's an empty command that is used within a renewed `\item` command, that then gets renamed to `\bigskip`.

My suspicion is something to do with trying to make the first occurrence of `\item` behave differently from subsequent occurrences; like can be achieved with a do-while loop; but I'm not sure.

Comment: It is initialized to empty and then redefined to `\bigskip`.  You surely do not want a big skip before the first item of your list.

Comment: Also, being defined inside an environment makes it local to the environment.  OTOH, being local it doesn't matter whether it was previously used or not, so \def would have been more appropriate.

Comment: That is what you get by using a template; some strange code that might not even be used. It really is the case that templates are golding newcommers back (broadly speaking).

Comment: @Johannes_B - Well, honestly, if there wasn't a template, I'd just use be using Microsoft Word for my resume. So I'm happy a template at least encouraged me to try tex :-) Also, I've been cleaning up. Replaced `\item` with my own command `\role` because it seemed wrong to `\renewcommand` such a widely used command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with the code posted but ignoring those and concentrating on `\inskip`

The usage is presumably

```
\begin{eventlist}
\item{aa}{bb}{cc}
\item{aa}{bb}{cc}
\item{aa}{bb}{cc}
\end{eventlist}
```

each item sets cc in bold and aa in small caps as a heading, followed by bb

Before each item,  `\inskip` is executed.

For the first item in each list this is defined to be empty, so does nothing, then that item redefines it to be `\bigskip` so before each item after the first there is a vertical space of `\bigskipamount` added.

On its own that would have given a vertically symmetric layout with no space above or below and a big skip between items. Then slightly strangely the end code of the environment adds `\bigskip` after the last item, having gone to some effort as described above not to add a skip before the first item.

Comment: Ah! And it just came to me that "inskip" must mean "initial skip."